# mPDF, incorrect container floating

Tags: mpdf

I want set style "float: left" to image container. But this floating is not correct.

Example: http://prntscr.com/1mkdsr

My html code:

```
<div class="image" style="float: left; width: 270px;">
    <img src="...." />
    <div class="image-title">Image description</div>
</div>

Text......
```

And i try set text to another container:

```
<div class="image" style="float: left; width: 270px;">
    <img src="...." />
    <div class="image-title">Image description</div>
</div>

<div class="text">Text......</div>
```

But not working. How to set a correct this floating? Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you have does exactly what it should do. As you set the floating to the first DIV, that means that all the text that comes after this will "run around" the image, that means that the text will be on the right side of the image, exactly how your screenshot shows it.
If I understand you correctly and you want the text to continue under the image, you have to clear the floating, so that normal page flow continues.

```
<div class="text" style="clear:both">Text......</div>
```

This should solve your issue